# How can I add in Apache Feature Policy Header?

Tags: security, apache-2.4, http-headers

I have a multimedia site which offers users to upload their own media (video,music) or embed media from sites like YouTube, Vimeo etc.

Recently, new header is being announced. I tried to add this header but I believe I made a mistake somewhere.

This is how I tried to add this header;

```
Header always set Feature-Policy "vibrate 'self'; usermedia '*'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; sync-xhr 'self' mysiteURL.com"
```

Getting these error below;

```
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'vibrate'.
(index):1 Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'usermedia'.
(index):1 Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized origin: 'mysiteURL.com'.
(index):1 Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'vibrate'.
(index):1 Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'usermedia'.
(index):1 Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized origin: 'mysiteURL.com'.
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where do you have these errors? Your directive seems correct and your error message does not look like to be from Apache itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are web browser errors not Apache errors. So the browser just doesn't support turning on of off of those features. They are very new so [support for this header](https://caniuse.com/#feat=feature-policy) is not great at the moment.

The Chrome features [supported so far can be seen in the code](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#component%3A%20Blink%3EFeaturePolicy) and it can be seen that `vibrate` and `usermedia` are not yet supported by Chrome.

You also appear to have a few syntax errors, specifically:

```
usermedia '*'
```

Should not have quotes around the star (though this is difficult to tell since it is not yet supported and [at least one Google document also states this incorrectly](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k0Ua-ZWlM_PsFCFdLMa8kaVTo32PeNZ4G7FFHqpFx4E/edit)).

```
sync-xhr 'self' mysiteURL.com
```

URLs should be prefixed with the scheme (`https://`).

So, for now, you could change your header to this to avoid those errors, (though you might want to add `vibrate` and `usermedia` back in if they ever become supported later):

```
Header always set Feature-Policy "microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; sync-xhr 'self' https://mysiteURL.com"
```

Comment: could you please suggest how to add the Feature-Policy for Nginx? Because I am receiving errors in Chrome

Comment: What are you trying and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2020**

The `Feature Policy` has been changed to `Permissions Policy` and the usage is slightly different now. I thought this might be helpful here because this post has been viewed many times.

`Header always set Permissions-Policy "vibrate=(self), usermedia=(*), microphone=(none), payment=(none), sync-xhr=(self 'mysiteURL.com')"`

[image]

More details: [Hello Permissions Policy](https://scotthelme.co.uk/goodbye-feature-policy-and-hello-permissions-policy/)